# `stub` for Class in rspec2

Tags: ruby, rspec

```
describe SomeThing do
  before :all do
    # ...
    FooClass.stub(:fooMethod).with('a').and_return("something")
  end
end
```

Worked cool with `rspec 1`.

I've updated to `rspec 2`, and this is what i'm receiving for this line now:

```
Failure/Error: 
   FooClass.stub(:fooMethod).with('a').and_return("something")
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `stub' for FooClass::Class
```

The [rspec api](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/frames) but says: `Person.stub(:find) { person }`

What am i missing?

Comment: What command are you using to run the spec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this inside an `it` or `before` block?

Stubs are not supported in `before :all` blocks. Stubs and mocks get cleared after each example. You can read more about this [here](http://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/92). Change the `before :all do` to `before do` and this should work.

Comment: in `describe ... before :all do` block

Comment: oops, sorry. Should have seen that in your code..Can you move the code inside an `it` or change the `before :all do ... end` to simply `before do ... end`?

Comment: Seems like `before :all do` -> `before do` fixed the issue, not pretty sure yet

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `before :all do`? Make sure you are clear on the difference of `before all` and `before`.  Glad that its working now.

Comment: Does `before` alias for `before :each`?

Comment: Besides, i wonder what's the reason for that kind of stuff not to work in `before :all`?..

Comment: Yes, `before` aliases to `before :each`. And stubs are not supported in `before :all` blocks. Stubs and mocks get cleared after each example. You can read more about this at: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/92

Comment: Please, add this to your answer.