# mock Rails.env.development? using rspec

Tags: rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I am writing a unit test using rspec.

I would like to mock Rails.env.develepment? to return true. How could I achieve this?.

I tried this

```
Rails.env.stub(:development?, nil).and_return(true)
```

it throws this error

```
activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/string_inquirer.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `any_instance' for "test":ActiveSupport::StringInquirer (NoMethodError)
```

Update
ruby version ruby-2.0.0-p353,
rails 4.0.0,
rspec 2.11

```
describe "welcome_signup" do
    let(:mail) { Notifier.welcome_signup user }

    describe "in dev mode" do
      Rails.env.stub(:development?, nil).and_return(true)
      let(:mail) { Notifier.welcome_signup user }
      it "send an email to" do
        expect(mail.to).to eq([GlobalConstants::DEV_EMAIL_ADDRESS])
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should stub in `it`, `let`, `before` blocks. Move your code there and it will work

And this code works in my tests (maybe your variant can work as well)

```
Rails.env.stub(:development? => true)
```

for example

```
describe "in dev mode" do
  let(:mail) { Notifier.welcome_signup user }

  before { Rails.env.stub(:development? => true) }

  it "send an email to" do
    expect(mail.to).to eq([GlobalConstants::DEV_EMAIL_ADDRESS])
  end
end
```

Comment: didn't really help. getting `method_missing': undefined method `stub' for "test":ActiveSupport::StringInquirer (NoMethodError)

Comment: strange - I checked in my tests before posting code. Provide your code and versions of gems (rails, rspec)

Comment: thanks it worked. so what is the reason to have it in the it, let, or before blocks? i thought "send an email to" it block should access anything in the outer describe block.

Comment: found it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955733/stub-for-class-in-rspec2/11955986#11955986

Comment: not really so. It's a rather complicated question. If say in two words: `stub` is a `Rspec` method and Rspec works only inside mentioned blocks. Other reason is you should stub method before it is called but when you launch a test - Rspec reads only needed lines: `before all`, `before each`, `it` blocks (`let` blocks are lazy load)

Answer (score 82):

There is a much better way described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24052647/362378

```
it "should do something specific for production" do 
  allow(Rails).to receive(:env) { "production".inquiry }
  #other assertions
end
```

This will provide all the functions like `Rails.env.test?` and also works if you just compare the strings like `Rails.env == 'production'`

Comment: This is the RSpec 3 way to do it.

Comment: A cleaner way of getting an inquiry object is to do `"production".inquiry`

Comment: @DavidBackeus: I disagree, I find Rails' way of polluting objects with unrelated behavior not clean, but it is definitely handy. Thx

Answer (score 3):

With rspec 3:

```
allow(Rails).to receive(:env).and_return(OpenStruct.new(staging?: true))
```