# RSpec stub environment helper

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, stub

I've got a lib/require/environment_helpers.rb file that contains helper methods.  There are more methods, but it's not wrapped in a module.

```
def development?
  Rails.env.development?
end

def test?
  Rails.env.test?
end
```

I'm trying to stub these methods out and am not having any luck. I've tried:

```
before :each
  allow(Rails.env).to receive(:production?) { false }
end

before :each
  allow(Rails).to receive(:production?) { false }
end

before :each
  allow(ServiceUnderTest).to receive(:production?) { false }
end
```

Comment: check this question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153666/mock-rails-env-development-using-rspec/21154359 and especially this part of code `receive(:env).and_return(ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new("production"))`

Answer (score 0):

> trying to stub these methods

You can stub it like this

```
before :each do
  rails_env = double(:rails_env, development?: false)
  expect(Rails).to receive(:env).and_return(rails_env)
  expect(rails_env).to receive(:development?).and_return(false)
end
```